# Can't see a file I wrote on SD card using native code c++ (dart:ffi) flutter

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, android-permissions, ffi

I have been processing images with openCV using foreign function interface (ffi),
I'd like to get a greater control during the debugging process for understanding what is the output in each phase of the image processing.

Therefore I decided to take a simple approach to write each output on the sdcard.
but for some reason I can't see any file I write.

It seems even for a simple black image i can't write onto the sdcard:

```
cv::Mat out1;
out1 = cv::Mat::zeros(256,256, CV_8U);
cv::imwrite("black.jpg", out1);
```

also have also tried a simple text file in c++:

```
ofstream myfile;
if (IsPathExist("/sdcard/DCIM/Screenshots/") == true){
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "NATIVE", "Attention: Path found!!");    
}
else{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "NATIVE", "Attention: Path NOT found!!");       
}
myfile.open("/sdcard/DCIM/Screenshots/example.txt");
if (myfile.fail()) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "NATIVE", "Attention: ERROR could not open the file!!!");    
}

myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
```

I keep getting a failure while trying to creating/accessing the new file ("Attention: ERROR could not open the file!!!"),

It seems it's a permission issue, so I have added to the file **example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

and have added to the file **android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but still the same failures as before.

On my system I have:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on Linux, locale en_IL)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at /home/my_user/development/flutter
    • Framework revision b22742018b (5 weeks ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.


[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 52.2.1
    • Dart plugin version 201.9317
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • POCOPHONE F1 (mobile) • c44ca636 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
```

Moreover from my **example/android/app/build.gradle**:

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
    
        defaultConfig {
...
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 30
....
        }
```

Can somebody suggest what am I missing? thank you.

Comment: Have you granted permission at runtime first? https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: I see you are using it for debugging purposes only, so you can grant permission manually in app info screen or via adb

Comment: @Dima Rostopira  I have manually granted permission to allow the flutter app to take pictures and record video and audio, but it still fails.

Comment: You have to grant WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE manually the same way

Comment: @DimaRostopira I don't get a popup on the screen for requesting  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. How come? can you please elaborate.

Comment: Try this library: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: have you solved this?